# Does SQL Server 2008 R2 SP2 include RTM-CU14?

Tags: sql-server

Does SQL Server 2008 R2 *Service Pack 2* include *Cumulative Update 14*, and prior, for SQL Server 2008 R2?

Comment: The master KB is here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2630455 However I cannot get it to load today for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Simply said, YES IT DOES. Obviously - Sp2 supersedes any Sp1 level official pack.

There MAY be an issue that is still open due to timing delays (hotfix released after Sp was too far to integarte it), but then you also should install Sp2 level CU's ;) obviously.